# String interning and equality operators

Tags: .net, string

I was just reading this site which states: `Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references...a and b do not refer to the same string instance`
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx ).

I haven't checked the internals of the `String` class, but is that statement correct?  From what I understand, the reason a `String` is immutable is due to string interning.  In other words, only one copy of a string is stored for each unique value.  All `String` variables with identical values reference the same object.  I thought that was why `"a" == "a"` works -- not because it is `defined to compare the values`.  If it were checking the value, then the strings would have to be compared character by character, causing significant performance considerations, and eliminating one of the main reasons to use string interning to begin with.

Maybe they over-simplified, but I think it's misleading to suggest that the `String` equality operators have been defined differently than other reference types.  Please do correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: FYI: Only compile time string literals are interned by default, so you may have multiple copies of strings with the same text if they are created at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String *can* be interned, but they don't have to be.  String literals are interned (by default - this can be changed with the `CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning` attribute now), and instances created at runtime could be, but in general aren't unless special steps are taken (like calling `String.Intern()`).

There can be multiple instances of stings that have the same value.

Also, there are reasons besides being able to intern strings that they're immutable - immutability is mainly so objects holding references don't have to worry about those values changing 'behind their backs'.  So it's more along the lines of being able to inter strings is a consequence of immutability, rather than strings must be immutable so we can intern them.

Comment: Any rule about when strings are interned or not?  This would have to be done at runtime since strings can come from external systems.

Comment: In generally you probably don't have to worry about it.  But if you are thinking about interning strings, I think the main rule is that you only want to intern strings that are likely to have a long lifetime (like as long as the application).  The docs for `String.Intern()` has more detail.

Comment: I seem to recall that the only time a string is interned at runtime is when you use them in a `switch` statement.

Comment: @Lasse why would that intern? String switch works on a hidden dictionary mapping strings (from `ldstr`) to ints, then it is a table-jump. No need to intern runtime strings for that.

Comment: To clarify: I'm curious; I'm not saying it is right/wrong; it just sounds anti-intuitive

Comment: So if you do something like `string a = GetExternalString(); string b = String.Intern(a);` you are unnecessarily allocating `a`?  Would `string b = String.Intern(GetExternalString())` prevent that (assuming the value of a is already interned)?

Comment: @Nelson: unless `GetExternalString()` is returning an already interned string, then there will be a non-interned string allocated momentarily.  Presumably, the reference to it will be gone shortly (especially in your last example), so it'll be collected quite soon. But it does have to be collected.

Comment: @Marc: I recall hearing the same as what Lasse said (after he reminded me). But long enough ago that I don't remember details.  Once both strings are known to be interned (and that happen at load time with `case` labels), the comparison becomes a simple reference compare.  Chris Brumme discusses this a bit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/22/51371.aspx  and Brad Abrams hints at it being used in `switch`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/08/14/50227.aspx

Comment: Note that those blog articles are pretty old - it's quite possible that things have changed in the last decade (especially since interning of literals is optional now - I wonder if `CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning` applies to `case` labels?). I should look at an ildasm, but I don't have the ability at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Not all strings are interned; *literals* / *constants* from the compiler (and specifically, the `ldstr` IL code) are interned automatically, and you can intern/check manually - but ***most*** strings constructed at runtime (for example from user-input, loaded from files/databases, or concatenation with values) are *not*. So yes: it is necessary to do value checks too.

Interning is an optimisation only; it needs to work without it.

Comment: That makes sense, though I assumed that at runtime it would check the intern list before allocating a new string.  Sure, it would also have performance implications every time you concatenate strings.

Comment: @Nelson it does not do that automatically; only on explicit request, or via `ldstr`; most strings are so short-lived (gen0) that it is cheaper to allocate them and let them die than it is to cripple every allocation with lots of checks

Comment: So I learn something new... This reminds me of the "to index or not" issue in general.  An index will speed up your reads, but slow down your writes.

Answer (score 2):

No, the docs say exactly what they mean: for `String`s, the `==` operators compares the values of the strings, character by character. Just because a given is a reference type doesn't mean it has to compare by reference; that's why [`operator==` can be overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx).

A bit of poking with Reflector reveals that `String`'s `operator==(String, String)` calls `Equals(String, String)`, which uses unsafe pointers to compare the underlying values.